# Como saber si una cadena pertenece a un conjunto?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Este es el problema:

una cadena pertenece al conjunto M de cadenas formadas por los caracteres 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '(', ')' y que tienen sus paréntesis balanceados (es decir, cada paréntesis que abre tiene un paréntesis de cierre, el cual aparece después).

Esto es lo que llevo:

```
introducir el código aquí
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

char arr[100];

cin>>arr;

bool correcto = false;

for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    if(arr[i] = 'a' && arr[i] == 'b' && arr[i] == 'c'
    && arr[i] == 'd' && arr[i] == '(' && arr[i] == ')'){
        correcto = true;
    } 
}

cout<<correcto;
```

}

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que tiene que dar de resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto el programa me marca solo cero, en cuarquier cadena que yo ponga.

Answer (score 1):

No estás trabajando con física cuántica, luego es literalmente imposible que una variable tenga varios valores a la vez:

```
if(arr[i] = 'a' && arr[i] == 'b' && arr[i] == 'c'
&& arr[i] == 'd' && arr[i] == '(' && arr[i] == ')'){
    correcto = true;
}
```

Ese condicional solo se ejecutará cuando la variable `arr[i]` sea igual a todas y cada una de las opciones que ahí estás poniendo.

Lo que tu realmente pretendes es comprobar que en cada posición del array se encuentra una de esas opciones, es decir, para cada posición del array **o** hay una `a`, **o** una `b` **o** una `c` **o** una `d` **o** paréntesis.

Además, fíjate que lo de la `a` no es una comparación sino una asignación.

Corregido quedaría así:

```
if (arr[i] == 'a' || arr[i] == 'b' || arr[i] == 'c'
 || arr[i] == 'd' || arr[i] == '(' || arr[i] == ')')
{
    correcto = true;
}
```

Pero ahora tendrás otro problema, y es que el algoritmo ahora te marcará falsos positivos. Por ejemplo:

```
aAAAAAAA -> correcto
```

Este problema lo tienes porque estás haciendo la evaluación al revés. Tu tienes que asumir que, en principio, la cadena será correcta, y únicamente cuando te encuentres un caracter no válido, la marcas como no válida:

```
bool correcto = true;

for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != 'a' && arr[i] != 'b' && arr[i] != 'c'
     && arr[i] != 'd' && arr[i] != '(' && arr[i] != ')')
    {
        correcto = false;
    }
}
```